# Global sum wrong with multi threads in JAVA

Tags: java

I'm new to multi-threads in Java and I made a little code to see how it works. I have `global = 0` as a global int variable, and with a `for` loop I initialize a lot of threads (100) to add 1 to my global variable. 
 At the end of the code the result should be 100, but is not. I have sometimes 99 at the end of the code or any other number (around 100). So my question is, why the threads "fight" between them and don't make the sum right?

```
public class test extends Thread {
    public static int global =0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
                String stream = String.valueOf(i);
                new test2(stream).start();
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(global);
    }
    public test(String str) {
        super(str);
    }
    public void run() {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(getName());
        global = global+1;
        System.out.println("El hilo "+a+" tiene el número "+global);
    }
}
```

I know that I don't need `int a = Integer.parseInt(getName());`, but I pretend yo use the name in the future. And, if I delete that now the result is wrong anyway.

Comment: You should read a good tutorial or book on multithreading - it is a fairly complicated subject and if you don't understand the details you will get more issues like this one...

Comment: "So my question is, why the threads "fight" between them and don't make the sum right?" - This is the fundamental problem statement of concurrency. It is too big a question to get into here

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would  make it thread-safe.

Comment: Did you ever read any Java articles about thread safe? You should read it first before try to test/code thread safe.

Comment: [The Java concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) is really worth reading.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a classic race condition.

One of your threads, call it "A", has read the value `global`, say `10`, and added `1` to it, but it hasn't stored the value `11` back to `global`.

Another of your threads, call it "B", now is reading the "old" value of `global`, `10`, it's adding `1` to it, and it stores the value `11` back to `global`.

Then thread "A" finally is allowed store its value `11` back to `global`.  Two increments have taken place, but the net result is that only one increment has effectively taken place.

This occurs because the operation of incrementing the value and storing it back to a variable is not *atomic*.  That means that there are multiple separate operations that if interrupted, could yield an incorrect result.

You must create a `synchronized` block to enforce the operation being atomic.  You can lock on the class object itself.

```
synchronized (test.class) {
    global = global+1;
}
```

As an alternative, you may make your `global` variable an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), which handles atomic updates for you.

Comment: Or - better - use an `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: Reads should also be synchronized, not just writes. AtomicInteger is the way to go though.

Answer (score 7):

That's because

```
global = global+1;
```

is not an atomic operation. It consists in

- reading the value of global,
- compute the incremented value,
- assigning the result to global

So, since the threads execute concurrently, you can have a race condition:

- thread 1 reads 34
- thread 2 reads 34
- thread 1 computes the incremented value
- thread 2 computes the incremented value
- thread 1 assigns 35 to global
- thread 2 assigns 35 to global

multi-threading is all about making sure shared state is correctly modified. You need to synchronize every access to the global variable to make its changes atomic. Another way would be to use an AtomicInteger, which allows being incremented in an atomic way.

Answer (score 3):

The following statement is not thread-safe:

```
global = global+1;
```

**Imagine this scenario:**

thread#1 reaches this statement. It reads `global` which is `0`. At this time, thread#2 reaches to the same statement. It reads `global` which is still `0`. Now, thread#1 adds 1 to 0 and saves the total 1 in `global`. thread#2 continues, adds 1 to 0 and saves the total 1 to `global` as well.

---

- See [Race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Answer (score 1):

To make it thread safe the simplest way would be to synchronize access to "global" by something. For example by your class itself (which is Object too)

```
public class test extends Thread {
public static int global = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        String stream = String.valueOf(i);
        new test(stream).start();
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println(global);
}

public test(String str) {
    super(str);
}

public void run() {
    int a = Integer.parseInt(getName());
    synchronized (test.class) {
        global = global + 1;
    }
    System.out.println("El hilo " + a + " tiene el número " + global);
}
```

}